# IK not moving correctly

Tags: inverse-kinematics

I'm having an issue with IK, despite it always working fine previously. I've set up an IK on the lower leg bone as shown below. The IK target is the bone opposite the foot, and the IK pole target is the floating bone. The chain length is 2 and the pole rotation is 90 so that the leg faces forward. WHen I try and move the bone with G, all I get is the rotation as see in the gif below. The pole target and IK target are both set to not deform. Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

[image]

Comment: SHikha Mittal is right, you don't move the right bone, if it still doesn't fix your problem, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

You are moving the wrong bone , the Target is the bone that is used to move the IK , Thats why it is called Controller bone